# Square with a diagonal, asterix pattern in C

Tags: c

I have to write a program that will print a square made of asterisks with one diagonal, with the side of n asterisks. If n is 5, the pattern would be

```
*****
*  **
* * *
**  *
*****
```

My erroneous code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
  int n,row,i,star;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(row=1;row<=n;row++){
    if(row==1||row==n){
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    printf("*");
      }
    }
    else { for(star=1;star<=n;star++){
        if((star==1)||(star=n-row+1)||(star==n))
          printf("*");
        else printf(" ");
       }
    }

    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Instead of doing its job, it prints infinite asterisks.

Comment: Next time check your code for typos before posting.

Comment: And try more conventional code styling.

Comment: I'm sorry, English is not my native language, thanks for the feedback, I will keep a eye on my spelling and improve my code styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning instead of comparing.

```
if((star==1)||(star=n-row+1)||(star==n))
                   ^
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I should really keep an eye on these semantic errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
       int i,j,n;

       printf("Enter the number of lines to be printed:");
       scanf("%d",&n);
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
             printf("*");
       printf("\n");
       for(i=0;i<n-2;i++)
       {
              printf("*");
              for(j=0;j<n-2;j++)
              {
                    if(j==(n-3-i))
                    {
                        printf("*");
                    }
                    else{
                     printf(" ");
                    }
              }
              printf("*\n");
       }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
              printf("*");
        printf("\n");
}
```